# Storing chat history twice Ejabberd [PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql, ejabberd

I am able to store the messages in the postgres database. But when i try to make the chat between two users, the messages are saving two times in my database. You can find the screenshot here

[image]

In this screenshot, I am just sending two messages. From yashwanth to shabda (1 msg) and from shabda to yashwanth (1 msg). But saving the message two times in my database. I dont know where is the problem. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. A message as a a sender and a recipient. If both users are on the same server, it means it will be stored as send and stored as received.

Comment: Thanks Mickael. I realised the way of saving the messages right now. it is stored as sender message and receiver message when using the same server. Thanks a lot. Very helpful